# Custom ID in session handling by Java Servlet API

Tags: java, session, web-applications, servlets

Is it possible to assign a custom ID to a HTTP session through Servlet API?

I know that session handling from any application server, Tomcat for example, it's enough good to generate unique IDs. But I have custom unique session IDs based on information per user and time, so it won't be repeated.

And I looked at every documentation about session handling but nowhere I find what I need.

It's a requirement for a project, so if it's not possible, I need to know the reasons (or it's only not available through API?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Tomcat, you may be able to create a custom session manager (see [this discussion](http://markmail.org/message/im3wkoeskkgjaphv#query:tomcat%20custom%20session%20Manager+page:1+mid:lgl2bdm26avvjx37+state:results)).  You would then have access to the Tomcat [Session](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Session.html) object and could call setId.

Answer (score 3):

The servlet API does not support creating your own cookie value. In fact, it does not guarantee that sessions are maintained via cookies... it specifically states that they can be maintained via a mechanism such as "URL Rewriting". It DOES guarantee that the session is maintained in some fashion, and that pretty much requires some sort of unique ID which is passed to the browser and returned, but no mechanism is provided in the Servlet API for servlet code to control what value is used. Nor do common servlet containers that I know of (such as Tomcat) provide a means for controlling this value.

However, none of this should be a problem for you if I understand your requirements properly. Just because Tomcat (or whatever servlet container you use) is creating a unique ID based on its own algorithms (that contain things like cryptographically secure random number generators to prevent "guessing" of session IDs), doesn't mean that you cannot create a SEPARATE ID which meets your requirements (based on user and time, unique across all sessions... whatever you need). This ID can be stored in the session (if that's all you need), or can be stored on the browser in a separate cookie (if you need it maintained across sessions). The only effect would be that the browser was storing TWO cookies -- and most websites store many more cookies than that!

Answer (score 1):

Um...if you have the code to generate a unique ID, you can just do this:

```
/** 
 * The String key of the user id attribute.
 */
public static final String USER_ID_KEY = "userIdKey";

// Set the user attribute (createUniqueUserId's parameters and return type are up to you)
httpSession.setAttribute(USER_ID_KEY, createUniqueUserId());

// Retrieve the user attribute later
httpSession.getAttribute(USER_ID_KEY);
```

The HttpSession interface also provides a getId() method, which is documented [here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId()) (copying the documentation for reference):

> public java.lang.String getId()
>
> Returns a string containing the unique
> identifier assigned to this session.
> The identifier is assigned by the
> servlet container and is
> implementation dependent.
>
> Returns: a
> string specifying the identifier
> assigned to this session